# How to check whether a key already exists in a Kafka topic?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want a function, say checkKey() which should work as follows:

```
def checkKey(key):
    if(key in topic-name):
        return True
    return False
```

I could not find this in Kafka's documentation. I am aware that in order to deduplicate data, Kafka can update the key. However, I do not want the updation, I want to know whether it already exists or not. And if it exists, I want to update its value in the following way:

```
def updateValue(key):
    if(checkKey(key)):
        value of key in topic-name += 1
```

This I need to perform using Python, so code sample of the same would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) for that. Simply define a KTable for your topic using StreamBuilder.[table](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#table-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-) providing a name for the state store using `Materialized.as("store-name")` and then you can query it using [Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html), see that page for more examples but it's as simple as `streams.store("store-name", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()).get(key)`.

Comment: The question was tagged Python. You'll want to mention Kafka Streams requires JVM languages

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is not a table, it's a queue.  To see if a key exists in a topic, you need to read the entire topic or, if at all possible, keep a local copy of the topic.  You might be able to restrict your search to a specific partition if you know your partitioning logic.

That being said, Confluent has a streaming SQL engine called KSQL which *might* help you.  You can look it up [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/)

Comment: You can compute the partition for a known key to prevent scanning the whole topic

Comment: Which is still a sub-optimal solution.  I am working on a project which places 60+ billion records a day on a 40 partition topic.  Scanning a single partition would still be a nightmare.

Comment: I was just clarifying "scanning the whole topic" isn't necessary. KSQL would also need to scan a topic partition to find a key (at least at first setup)

Comment: Correct.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @nads

How can I avoid duplication based on the key? Can you illustrate an example in Python?